# Jquery validation text cannot contain

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin to validate some text fields on the fly. One of the rules is the field cannot contain `'http'`.  How would I modify the `validate()` method to achieve this?

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserDetails", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "registerform" }))
{
    <input id="Facebook" minlength="2" name="Facebook" placeholder="eg: Joe.Bloggs123" type="text" value>
    ...
}

<script>
    $('#registerform').validate({
        // ...?
    })
</script>
```

Edit:  I tried adding a the validator.addmethod but it still doesn't work. SO here is what I have in the script:

```
 $('#registerform').validate();

jQuery.validator.addMethod("Facebook", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf('http') >= 0);
        }, "*Please just use your userid, not the full url");
```

Also I would need to validate a lot of these, is it not possible to add a custom class and select from that?

Comment: u can use customise validation method for this

Comment: read the documentation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ and show us what you have tried

Comment: edited OP with the method I'm trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what finally worked for me:

```
<script>
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkhttp", function(value, element) {
                        return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf('http') < 0) && (value.indexOf('www') < 0);
                    }, "*Please just use your userid, not the full url");

                    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkhttp = { checkhttp: true };

                $('#registerform').validate();
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UserDetails", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "registerform" }))
{
     <input id="Facebook" class="checkhttp" name="Facebook" placeholder="eg: Joe.Bloggs123" type="text" value>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for your case but i suggest you use regex

```
 if( $('#Facebook').val().indexOf('http') >= 0 ) {
  alert('Contains http');
 } else {
  alert('Doesn't contain http');
```

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, i haven't read the question right.

Add a jQuery validator

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DoesNotContain", function(value, element)
{
    return this.optional(element) || (indexOf('http') < 0);
}, "* Can't contain http");
```

Comment: this is not an jquery.validation implementation